# Django emailing the user data from a model

Tags: python, django, email, django-admin, django-email

I Have a django function that bans users and adds them to a `Banned_User` table, which has a profile and `reason_reported` column to mark them as banned.

I'm looking to send an email to the user,once banned with a list of reasons from the `report_reasons` field  in the `banned_user` table as to why they have been banned.

```
def banning_users(self, request, queryset):

#BANNING FUNCTION
for obj in queryset:
    if hasattr(obj, 'user'):
        # This object is a Profile, so lookup the user
        profile = obj
        user = obj.user
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()

    #ADDING TO TABLE
    banned_user = profile.banned_profile.create(profile=profile)
    reports = banned_user.profile.user_reported_report.all()
    banned_user.save()
    for report in reports:
        banned_user.report_reason.add(report)

    # EMAIL FUNCTION
    subject = 'Ban'
    message = 'You have been banned for the following reasons: []'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [user.email]
    send_mail( subject, message,email_from, recipient_list)

self.message_user(request, "User is banned and Email has been sent")
```

**Banned User model**

```
class Banned_User(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
return str.join(str(self.profile), str(self.report_reason.report_reason))
#return self.profile
#return str.join(str(self.profile), str(self.report_reason))

profile = models.ForeignKey(
    'Profile',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name='banned_profile'
)

report_reason = models.ManyToManyField(
    'Report',
    #on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=True,
    #null=True,
)

date_banned = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False,)
```

**report model**

```
    class Report(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
    return str.join(str(self.user_reported), str(self.datetime_sent))

TOXICITY = 'Toxicity'
SPORTSMANSHIP = 'Poor sportsmanship'

REPORT_REASON_CHOICES = (
    (TOXICITY, 'Toxicity'),
    (SPORTSMANSHIP, 'Unsportsmanlike Behaviour'),
)

session = models.ForeignKey(
    'Session',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
)

user_reported = models.ForeignKey(
    'Profile',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name='user_reported_report',
)

sent_by = models.ForeignKey(
    'Profile',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    blank=False,
    null=False,
    related_name='sent_by_report',
)

report_reason = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    choices=REPORT_REASON_CHOICES,
    default=TOXICITY,
)

datetime_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
```

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: My question is how do i go about sending the reported_reasons which are variables to the users email?

Comment: You can add a `django template` into your email and pass it the `reported_reasons` variable. You can get the template in your function with [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) and then pass it to `send_email`with the `html_message` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a model to store the user and reasons and send the email in views.

For example:
in models.py

```
class BannedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name='banned', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reasons = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Then in views.py

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail

msg = '''Hello {},

We are sorry to inform you that you have been banned from {} 
for the following reasons {}.

This will take effect immediately. Thank you for you understanding.
'''.format(user.username, sitename, user.banned.reasons)

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    msg,
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com',],
)
email.send(fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to upload my models before,I already have models existing